# svg image beneath text (text decoration)

Tags: html, css

I'd like to add an SVG image of a curly bracket beneath and between two words just like in the image below.

[image]

Since I'd like it to be responsive I thought to include the image directly in the HTML in a span tag between the two words - but this just creates a gap between the words (expected).

What's the best way to do this?
I wish there was a way to add an image to the text-decoration-style attribute.

forgive me if this has been asked before -- designer looking to improve html/css

Comment: Hope you don't mind, I changed your post to include the picture inline. I figured you probably meant to do it this way.

Comment: Oh, thank you William!

Answer (score 0):

You can set the padding-top and bottom of the curly bracket to a negative value. But I am not sure if it is the best way though.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect way to do this in pure SVG of any version. I will give an example of how to reach a case-by-case solution in SVG 1.0, although the technique will work in both versions 1.1 and 2.0.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="512" height="256" viewBox="0 0 512 256">
    <g stroke="red">
        <!-- frame and center lines for reference -->
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white"/>
        <line x1="50%" x2="50%" y1="0%" y2="100%"/>
        <line x1="0%" x2="100%" y1="50%" y2="50%"/>
    </g>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" text-anchor="middle" font-size="500%" font-family="Sans-Serif">Hello world</text>
    <text x="50%" y="50%" font-size="500%" baseline-shift="-16" font-family="Sans-Serif" transform="rotate(90,256,128) translate(4,0)">}</text>
</svg>
```

[image: Visual rendering of code]

The basic steps for this are as follows.

1. Put your primary text wherever.
2. Put your `'}'` in the same place,  as the primary text. However, this text should have `text-anchor="start"` (default) regardless of the anchor of the primary text.
3. Rotate the curly bracket text about its x and y baselines. In the example, this is done as `transform="rotate(90,256,128)"`.
4. Change the horizontal position of the curly bracket by changing its `baseline-shift` attribute. A more negative value moves the curly bracket left, and a more positive value moves it right.
5. Change the vertical position of the curly bracket by applying a horizontal (confusing, I know; vertical and horizontal were switched by the rotation) translation. You'll want to move the curly bracket text a little lower. To do this, translate x positively. In the given example, the curly bracket is move 4 units downward by `translate(4,0)`.

Like I said, this isn't perfect, and you'll have to do some trial and error every time you create a new image. However, once you get it right, the result will be reactive and scalable like the rest of your image. The only important caveat is that you must set the `viewBox` attribute if you ever intend to change `width` or `height`, although you should be doing this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have created something with CSS and `after` pseudo element. Please check if this works for you. You can also use an image/svg background as in my second example below.

[image]

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  content: "{";
  left: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(270deg);
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Produc<span class="bg">t D</span>esigner</h1>
```

**Below example is using a background image. You can replace it with SVG.**

```css
.bg {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.bg:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -20px;
  width: 38px;
  height: 25px;
  content: ' ';
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2tKv.png');
  background-size: 100% auto;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  left: 3px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>This example is using a background image
  <h1>

    <h1>I am a Produc<span class="bg">t D</span>esigner</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution without having to use an SVG. Can you wrap each word in a `span`?
If so, then all you need to do is this:

```
span {
  position: relative; /* for curly brace positioning */
}
span:first-child::after {
  content: " "; /* space after the first word */
}
span:first-child::before {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: bottom right;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(40%);
  content: "{";
}
```

For moving the curly brace closer/further to/from the heading, use additional `translateX(#)` in the transform, for example like this:

`transform: rotate(-90deg) translateY(40%) translateX(-5px);`

Check the snippet [here](https://codepen.io/huuuda_aus/pen/RwGzVoK) (I added borders for visual clarity).

EDIT: Regarding brace's finer horizontal positioning, as William Rosenbloom mentioned below, you can use `baseline-shift` instead of `translateY()`.